# Do turtles execute the function called by "aks turtles[ some code ]" one by one or all together?

Tags: multithreading, netlogo

```
some code

breed[cars]

ask cars[

some code

]
```

Is "some code" executed by cars one by one or do cars execute the code all together?

I ask it because I'm wondering if there's the need to manage multithreading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agents execute tasks one by one not at once. Following text is from NetLogo guide:

> "ask is serial, that is, the agents run the commands inside the ask
>   one at a time. "

`"ask-concurrent"` is a primitive for concurrent execution of tasks by an agent set , but it is used only for backward compatibility:

```
ask-concurrent agentset [commands]
```